# JSON data not loading - ExtJS

Tags: json, extjs, store

I cannot get any of my json data to load into my combobox. Here's my code:

app/data/mydata.json

```
{
    images: [
        {name: 'Image one', url:'/GetImage.php?id=1', size:46.5, lastmod: new Date(2007, 10, 29)},
        {name: 'Image Two', url:'/GetImage.php?id=2', size:43.2, lastmod: new Date(2007, 10, 30)}
    ]
}
```

inside my app.js

```
var store4 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    // store configs
    storeId: 'myStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'app/data/mydata.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'images',
            idProperty: 'name'
        }
    },
});...
```

my combobox inside app.js

```
{ xtype: 'combobox', queryMode: 'local', padding: 5,   store: store4, displayField: 'name', typeAhead: true, emptyText: 'JSON', id: 'test' },
```

Any ideas?
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

That isn't valid JSON:

1. Labels should be wrapped in quotes, eg `"name"`. You should also use double quotes, not single for quoting strings.
2. You can't use `new Date()` in JSON, it's not valid. Have a look at `Ext.data.Field` and the information around the `dateFormat` parameter. You send the date back as a string and give it a format so Ext can parse it for you.

Also, you're missing field definitions. You need to create an `Ext.data.Model` subclass with the fields you're going to use in the store.

```
Ext.define('Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'url', 'size']
});

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Image',
    // ..

});
```

Comment: I changed the quotes and got rid of the dates, but still no data shows in my combobox

Comment: It validates through JSONLint as well

Comment: You're also missing the field definitions.

Comment: field definitions? what are those?

Comment: Is this working for you because I just can't get my data to show

Comment: Put together a fiddle, I'm not going to try and enumerate all the possible things that might be wrong.